# Debugging in Google Chrome Dev Tools in an dvanced manner with Blackboxing

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, wildcard, blacklist

Within Google Chrome Dev Tools/debugger --> settings --> Blackboxing one can add files to blacklist those from popping up in the debugger.

Now I want to block more than one file at once with **one** wildcard. All those files to block do have the first two identical characters.

How to do this? I.e. neither "VM$" or "VM*" work...

Answer (score 0):

They are regular expressions, so `VM.*` should work.